# VS2010 SP1 performance explorer on XP SP3 : error messages

Tags: visual-studio-2010, profiling

I am running XP SP3 at home (yes, I know) and am running VS2010 Ultimate Edition SP1.

I am attempting to run a profiling session on a Winforms app.

The first thing that happens is that I get told,

> Unable to open profiler driver, would you like to upgrade credentials of [account name]?

My account is already an admin account, so I'm not sure what other options I have.

The second thing that happens, regardless of what I do, is that I get message `VSP1398`:

> The monitor was unable to start the VS performance driver.  An instance of the service is already running.

But as far as I can tell no such instance is running.  If it is, it must run for mere microseconds and then shut down.

I've tried a handful of things:  checking what version of .Net I'm targeting, changing the target CPU to x86, turning off my AV software. messing around with the security settings on the project. I get the same response every time.

I've tried doing a repair install, too, but that didn't change anything.

Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: Google "vsp1398" and review the first 3 hits.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you.  Although the first link related to VS 2008, it gave me information I could use.